# Как получить площадь элементов svg?

Tags: javascript, svg

Доброе время суток!

Мне нужно получить площадь фигур исключая двойное наложение. Фигуры могут быть трех типов (но при этом могут быть сжаты или вытянуты или повернуты):

[image]

Например, соединенная фигура может быть такой:

[image]

У меня есть возможность получить JSON:

```
{
    "objects": [{
        "type": "group",
        "originX": "left",
        "originY": "top",
        "left": 481,
        "top": 91,
        "width": 313,
        "height": 201,
        "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
        "stroke": null,
        "strokeWidth": 0,
        "strokeDashArray": null,
        "strokeLineCap": "butt",
        "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
        "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
        "scaleX": 1,
        "scaleY": 1,
        "angle": 0,
        "flipX": false,
        "flipY": false,
        "opacity": 1,
        "shadow": null,
        "visible": true,
        "clipTo": null,
        "backgroundColor": "",
        "fillRule": "nonzero",
        "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
        "transformMatrix": null,
        "skewX": 0,
        "skewY": 0,
        "objects": [{
            "type": "rect",
            "originX": "left",
            "originY": "top",
            "left": -103.5,
            "top": -43.5,
            "width": 146,
            "height": 100,
            "fill": "#eccdae",
            "stroke": null,
            "strokeWidth": 1,
            "strokeDashArray": null,
            "strokeLineCap": "butt",
            "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
            "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
            "scaleX": 1,
            "scaleY": 1,
            "angle": 0,
            "flipX": false,
            "flipY": false,
            "opacity": 1,
            "shadow": null,
            "visible": true,
            "clipTo": null,
            "backgroundColor": "",
            "fillRule": "nonzero",
            "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
            "transformMatrix": null,
            "skewX": 0,
            "skewY": 0,
            "rx": 0,
            "ry": 0
        },
        {
            "type": "circle",
            "originX": "left",
            "originY": "top",
            "left": -44.5,
            "top": -100.5,
            "width": 200,
            "height": 200,
            "fill": "#eccdae",
            "stroke": null,
            "strokeWidth": 1,
            "strokeDashArray": null,
            "strokeLineCap": "butt",
            "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
            "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
            "scaleX": 1,
            "scaleY": 1,
            "angle": 0,
            "flipX": false,
            "flipY": false,
            "opacity": 1,
            "shadow": null,
            "visible": true,
            "clipTo": null,
            "backgroundColor": "",
            "fillRule": "nonzero",
            "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
            "transformMatrix": null,
            "skewX": 0,
            "skewY": 0,
            "radius": 100,
            "startAngle": 0,
            "endAngle": 6.283185307179586
        },
        {
            "type": "triangle",
            "originX": "left",
            "originY": "top",
            "left": -156.5,
            "top": -63.5,
            "width": 112,
            "height": 104,
            "fill": "#eccdae",
            "stroke": null,
            "strokeWidth": 1,
            "strokeDashArray": null,
            "strokeLineCap": "butt",
            "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
            "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
            "scaleX": 1,
            "scaleY": 1,
            "angle": 0,
            "flipX": false,
            "flipY": false,
            "opacity": 1,
            "shadow": null,
            "visible": true,
            "clipTo": null,
            "backgroundColor": "",
            "fillRule": "nonzero",
            "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
            "transformMatrix": null,
            "skewX": 0,
            "skewY": 0
        }]
    }],
    "background": ""
}
```

Или SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="1600" height="400" viewBox="0 0 1600 400" xml:space="preserve">
<desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.6.1</desc>
<defs></defs>
<g transform="translate(637.5 191.5)" style="">
    <rect x="-73" y="-50" rx="0" ry="0" width="146" height="100" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: #eccdae; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-30 7)"/>
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="100" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: #eccdae; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(56 0) "/>
    <polygon points="-56 52,0 -52,56 52" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: #eccdae; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-100 -11)"/></g>
</svg>
```

Как мне проще всего получить площадь без двойного наложения?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039679/how-can-i-calculate-the-area-of-a-bezier-curve